# Communication Refused between 2 Docker Express Microservices

Tags: docker, express, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a full stack application with docker containers, currently I have various express microservice images, and a react nginx image that are all being proxied by nginx, when react makes a call to one of my microservices it has to make a synchronous request to another but I am getting connection refused and not sure why, i have tried to do this with both relative and absolute urls to no avail.

Here is my docker compose:

```
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx-service:
    image: sahilhakimi/topshelf-nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - identity-service
      - client-service
      - product-service
      - cart-service
    networks:
      - my_network
  client-service:
    image: sahilhakimi/topshelf-frontend:latest
    networks:
      - my_network
  identity-service:
    image: sahilhakimi/topshelf-identity:latest
    environment:
      TOKEN_KEY: 7e44d0deaa035296b0cb10b3ea46ac627707e51c277908b609c0739d1adafc22e7e543faf9d43028ae64cccdf506e7994a1b0075880aae61a6cdb87d087bc082759a12c398d7e3291fd54539f1b260c7a5f6c79e2c4d586a180ed42b93866583c8da85acf261939d2171ef4b18765a205ee35f8cd1b989a8473589642176f6d1
      REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY: b7fb9c5209f55dc4b50d0faef5b4a0b3bdaa81db1e813779ef6c064de0a934e0c2e027fe5e2a9ab7b6d6c06a5d7099ccd837f7698ba9b5a8bee5e1acd86823c0eb29945d4965fe0db59d95c2defb60dbebb1b034dd22132115f14a50e175bd44bc919a91b7b6731e25908fc3b8800d06e90c6b1288b42c8b2378c2a619931e33
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: AKIATQAAJCDKIHEBIK5B
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 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
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://root:rootpassword@mongodb_container:27017/Users?authSource=admin
      REDIS_PASSWORD: eYVX7EwVmmxKPCDmwMtyKVge8oLd2t81
      REDIS_HOST: cache
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      clientUrl: http://client-service:5173
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_container
      - cache
    networks:
      - my_network
  product-service:
    image: sahilhakimi/topshelf-product:latest
    environment:
      TOKEN_KEY: 7e44d0deaa035296b0cb10b3ea46ac627707e51c277908b609c0739d1adafc22e7e543faf9d43028ae64cccdf506e7994a1b0075880aae61a6cdb87d087bc082759a12c398d7e3291fd54539f1b260c7a5f6c79e2c4d586a180ed42b93866583c8da85acf261939d2171ef4b18765a205ee35f8cd1b989a8473589642176f6d1
      REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY: b7fb9c5209f55dc4b50d0faef5b4a0b3bdaa81db1e813779ef6c064de0a934e0c2e027fe5e2a9ab7b6d6c06a5d7099ccd837f7698ba9b5a8bee5e1acd86823c0eb29945d4965fe0db59d95c2defb60dbebb1b034dd22132115f14a50e175bd44bc919a91b7b6731e25908fc3b8800d06e90c6b1288b42c8b2378c2a619931e33
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: AKIATQAAJCDKIHEBIK5B
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 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
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://root:rootpassword@mongodb_container:27017/Products?authSource=admin
      KAFKA_HOST: kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - mongodb_container
      - kafka
    networks:
      - my_network
  cart-service:
    image: sahilhakimi/topshelf-cart:latest
    environment:
      TOKEN_KEY: 7e44d0deaa035296b0cb10b3ea46ac627707e51c277908b609c0739d1adafc22e7e543faf9d43028ae64cccdf506e7994a1b0075880aae61a6cdb87d087bc082759a12c398d7e3291fd54539f1b260c7a5f6c79e2c4d586a180ed42b93866583c8da85acf261939d2171ef4b18765a205ee35f8cd1b989a8473589642176f6d1
      REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY: b7fb9c5209f55dc4b50d0faef5b4a0b3bdaa81db1e813779ef6c064de0a934e0c2e027fe5e2a9ab7b6d6c06a5d7099ccd837f7698ba9b5a8bee5e1acd86823c0eb29945d4965fe0db59d95c2defb60dbebb1b034dd22132115f14a50e175bd44bc919a91b7b6731e25908fc3b8800d06e90c6b1288b42c8b2378c2a619931e33
      REDIS_PASSWORD: eYVX7EwVmmxKPCDmwMtyKVge8oLd2t81
      REDIS_HOST: cache
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      KAFKA_HOST: kafka:9092
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - kafka
    networks:
      - my_network
  mongodb_container:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    networks:
      - my_network
  cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass eYVX7EwVmmxKPCDmwMtyKVge8oLd2t81
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
    networks:
      - my_network

  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:latest
    networks:
      - my_network
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    networks:
      - my_network
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://:29092,INTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "addToCart:1:1,invalidCartProduct:1:1"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xmx256M -Xms128M"
      KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS: " -Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
  cache:
    driver: local
```

The request that is giving me trouble is in the cart service and currently looks like this:

```
  const response = await axios.post(
      "http://product-service:3001/api/product/checkout",
      {
        cart: JSON.parse(cart),
        token: req.body.token,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Cookie: `accessToken=${cookies.accessToken}; refreshToken=${cookies.refreshToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
```

and here is my nginx configuration as well,

```
upstream client{
    server client-service;
}
upstream identity{
    server identity-service:3000;
}
upstream product{
    server product-service:3001;
}
upstream cart{
    server cart-service:3002;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://client;

    }

    location /api/user/ {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://identity;
    }
    location /api/product/{
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://product;
    }
    location /api/cart/{
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://cart;
    }

}
```

The error log in my docker container is :

```
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3001
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3001
  }
}
```

I tried the above and was expecting my request to properly be made to product service without connection refused, i know that the request is initially being proxied to cart service as wanted by nginx

Comment: looking through error logs i also noticed this    
```` _currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3001/api/product/checkout',
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
````